# How to get GMT/IST details from timezone object?

Tags: java

How to get the zone info from timezone object?

I have a `TimeZone` java object and I need to display the info as below

`ex: IST - India Standard Time - (GMT+5.30)`

I can get the IST - id and display name (Indian Standard Time) and offset as `5:30`.

How to get the zone - GMT ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying in `zone-Id - zone-Name - (GMT standard offset)` format

1. set to required time zone
2. get required data from above object

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");

```
tz.getID()              // for zone-id
tz.getDisplayName()         // for zone-Name
tz.getOffset(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()) // for GMT standard offset
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")`. If you want to check if ID exists try  using `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.